# Google maps tiles only load when dragend is fired on touch device

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, touch

Im getting a strange issue with the Google maps API v3 lib. If I am on a full desktop PC with a mouse and I drag a map, tiles are loaded as the drag is happening.

However, on a mobile device with a touch screen this is not the case. It seems that the tiles only load at around the same time the dragend event is fired.

You can recreate this by going to any website hosting a map. Drag the map quite far with your mouse and you will see the tiles load as you drag. Then hit F12 (on Chrome) and toggle into device mode. Reload the page and try the same thing. You will notice that tiles are only loaded when u release the touch.

Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it because your computer is faster than your tablet? And what kind of touch device are you testing it on?

Comment: It does it on any touch device. Chrome in device mode, iPhone, iPad, android tablet, anything.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on desktop [Chrome, with Device Mode & Mobile Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) enabled to load the Google Maps for mobile devices. And I would observe the mentioned problem even on my mac.

It could be a designed nature, a default behavior on mobile devices to save data. You might able to use jquery and capture the event before it is passed into the maps, and then pan your map to the correct position... (well.. really?)

You can always go to the [Google Maps API bug reports and feature requests](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/) page, and do a feature request.

Comment: I think its more of a bug as it does not do it with the ios and android SDK

Comment: ummm.. no, I think the javascript sdk still load the maps as tiles (PNGs), while ios is able to load the maps as vector....

Answer (score 0):

Use the **use_slippy** parameter:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?use_slippy=true